# Posting a php script in a iframe using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

I have followed a tutorial on how to make a wysiwyg input text area. 
The text area works fine. The problem I am having is that I want to be able to give the user the option edit the information posted by the text area.

The information is stored in my DB and have queried the DB and put the information in a variable called $details. I want to put this inside the iframe.

Here is my form code.

```
<body onLoad="iFrameOn();" >
<form action="inventory_edit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="myform" method="post">
<div id="wysiwyg_cp" style="padding:8px; width:700px;">
              <input type="button" onClick="iBold()" value="B"> 
              <input type="button" onClick="iUnderline()" value="U">
              <input type="button" onClick="iItalic()" value="I">
              <input type="button" onClick="iFontSize()" value="Text Size">
              <input type="button" onClick="iForeColor()" value="Text Color">
              <input type="button" onClick="iHorizontalRule()" value="HR">
              <input type="button" onClick="iUnorderedList()" value="UL">
              <input type="button" onClick="iOrderedList()" value="OL">
              <input type="button" onClick="iLink()" value="Link">
              <input type="button" onClick="iUnLink()" value="UnLink">
              <input type="button" onClick="iImage()" value="Image">
            </div>
            <!-- Hide(but keep)your normal textarea and place in the iFrame replacement for it -->
            <textarea style="display:none;" name="myTextArea" id="myTextArea" cols="100" rows="14"><?php echo $details; ?> blah blah </textarea>

            <iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField" style="border:#000000 1px solid; width:700px; height:300px;" ></iframe>



      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Make Changes" onClick="javascript:submit_form();"/>
</form>
```

This is the javascript file

```
function iFrameOn(){ 
    richTextField.document.designMode = 'On';               
}
function iBold(){
    richTextField.document.execCommand('bold',false,null); 
}
function iUnderline(){
    richTextField.document.execCommand('underline',false,null);
}
function iItalic(){
    richTextField.document.execCommand('italic',false,null); 
}
function iFontSize(){
    var size = prompt('Enter a size 1 - 7', '');
    richTextField.document.execCommand('FontSize',false,size);
}
function iForeColor(){
    var color = prompt('Define a basic color or apply a hexadecimal color code for advanced colors:', '');
    richTextField.document.execCommand('ForeColor',false,color);
}
function iHorizontalRule(){
    richTextField.document.execCommand('inserthorizontalrule',false,null);
}
function iUnorderedList(){
    richTextField.document.execCommand("InsertOrderedList", false,"newOL");
}
function iOrderedList(){
    richTextField.document.execCommand("InsertUnorderedList", false,"newUL");
}
function iLink(){
    var linkURL = prompt("Enter the URL for this link:", "http://"); 
    richTextField.document.execCommand("CreateLink", false, linkURL);
}
function iUnLink(){
    richTextField.document.execCommand("Unlink", false, null);
}
function iImage(){
    var imgSrc = prompt('Enter image location', '');
    if(imgSrc != null){
        richTextField.document.execCommand('insertimage', false, imgSrc); 
    }
}
function submit_form(){
    var theForm = document.getElementById("myform");
    theForm.elements["myTextArea"].value = window.frames['richTextField'].document.body.innerHTML;
    theForm.submit();
}
```

I have spent hours trying to find a fix. This is what I added to try and add my php var to the iframe.

This is added to the iFrameOn() function

```
var theForm = document.getElementById('myform');
window.frame['richTextField'].document.body.innerHTML = theForm.elements['myTextArea'].value;
```

Sorry if this is a lot of code. thanks

**Edit:**
Here is what the text editor looks like. 
[image: WYSIWYG]

I want to be able to pre-populate the iFrame with content already in the database so the user can edit it.

Comment: nitpick: you don't "post a php". You "post to a php script".

Comment: @MarcB My bad. I just mean put my variable content into the iFrame

Comment: I'm not quite understanding exactly what the problem is here - at what stage are you having a problem? What result are you getting instead of what you want?

Comment: @DaveRandom basically I have an iframe that I want to populate with Information stored in a db. And the problem im having is getting the details into the iframe.

Comment: @DaveRandom I have edited my question to provide more detail.

Comment: @Will I'm guessing that you are expecting the `iFrameOn()` call to do the magic? I which case, I think the problem is that it is attached to the `onload` event of the parent window, and not the iframe - so it fires before the iframe is ready to render the content. Try moving the `onLoad="iFrameOn();"` attribute to the `<iframe>` instead of the `<body>`. **EDIT** actually, that won't work. Hang on a sec

Comment: Does the content displayed in the iframe update when you change the content in the textarea on the fly? I can't see how it would.

Comment: @DaveRandom Imagine that it is just a text input box. When the form is submitted the information in the box is stored in the db. I want to give the user the chance the edit the content in the box. So I get the var $details from the db and want to place it in the iFrame so the user can change is. I would like it to keep the WTSIWYG formatting though and still be able to parse that into the db.

Comment: Oh *wait* I see what you are doing now. Try changing your `iFrameOn()` function to [this](http://pastebin.com/6gSPJUHh).

Answer (score 1):

I sorted this out with an external file that was created dynamically and then called into the iframe. I could not find another way to do it with the Iframe.

This does however seem to sometimes give issues with multiple users - Luckily my project seemed to allow me to get away with this by creating a folder and file. Maybe think of using session variables to create it (As it will be unique) and on exit use JS to delete the file?

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for answering the question posted so long ago! Thanks